# ANTLR templated rules

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I'm using ANTLR 4 to parse an SQL subset and currently, I'm faced with a problem.
I need a rule for predicate with the following structure:

```
predicate
    :
    expr relation expr
    | between_clause
    | predicate OR predicate
    | predicate AND predicate
    | '(' predicate ')'
    ;
```

The issue here is an `expr` rule. There are different types of predicates where `expr` should be different, but the whole aforementioned structure is preserved.

I would like to parametrize the `predicate` rule in some way to automatically instantiate several rules for different predicate types (the rule above where specific `expr` types are substituted).

Is it possible in ANTLR 4?

P.S. I see two alternative options:

- Copy-paste `predicate` rule and substitute different `expr` rules manually
- Have all possible alternatives in the `expr` rule and verify that only one type of them is used for a specific predicate in the target language code

But both of them are looking bad enough. The first case leads to a combinatorial explosion, and the second one leads to accepting a lot of incorrect predicates on the grammar level.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible in ANTLR 4?

No, ANTLR does not have such a feature.

Your two alternatives are exactly how these things are commonly done in practice. Which one is preferable depends on how exactly the different replacements for `expr` differ.

> the second one leads to accepting a lot of incorrect predicates on the grammar level.

There'll always types of errors that you can't prevent in the grammar and that'll have to be handled in a separate phase. Type errors or undeclared variable errors for example. So having the grammar accept incorrect programs isn't unusual at all.